# Equivalent use of mysql datediff function in Laravel where clause

Tags: mysql, laravel

I Have following query for mysql.

phpMyAdmin 4.0.10.10

```
SELECT * FROM `table_name` WHERE DATEDIFF(NOW(), start_date) = 154
```

I need an equivalent query for Laravel to use DATEDIFF function in where clause.

Comment: Assuming start_date datatype is a date then there is nothing syntactically or logically incorrect with your query, what makes you think there is and can you provide sample data to support your thinking.

Comment: sorry i need query for laravel

Comment: Syntax is correct !  What is the error you getting ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As in you comment, what you need for laravel,

```
$oldDate = Carbon::now()->subDays(154));
Table::whereDate('start_date', '=', $oldDate);
```

Another way is:

```
DB::table('table_name')->whereRaw('DATEDIFF(current_date, start_date) = 154')->get();
```

Comment: Happy to help ! Few updates I suggested for your question do review and approve.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with something like this:

```
 SELECT * FROM `table_name` WHERE start_date = (NOW() - 154 days);
```

I will not recommend DATEDIFF in the WHERE cuz it could possibly impose a table scan. Instead, I suggest this:

```
 SELECT
 DATEDIFF(start_date, NOW()) AS daysDiffs
 FROM table_name
 WHERE start_date = DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL 154 DAYS);
```